# demo login/password with SMS confirmation for App Store Connect

Tags: authentication, sms, app-store-connect

To verify my app, my app is checked before being published to the App Store. The examiner demands to tell them the Demo login / password to log in to the application. However, there is a problem - I have authorization in the application through the Yandex authentication service. And if I provide them with a demo Username / password, then the first time they log into my application, confirmation will be performed via an SMS code that comes to me, and not to the verifier. That is, the verification service in the App Store Connect must first create its own Yandex account by specifying ITS phone number. But they don't create their own Yandex account, but require a username and password from me, like robots. Does anyone have a similar problem and how to get around it? demo login is not possible without SMS. This is a Yandex requirement

I gave them a demo username and password, they tried to log in with them, received a request to enter an SMS confirmation code (but this code came to my phone, not to them). And after that, they immediately rejected my offer, referring to the fact that I did not provide them with a username and password according to the rule:
Guideline 2.1 - Information Needed
We have started your app’s review, but we were unable to successfully access all or part of your app. In order for us to continue the review, we need to have a way to verify all app features and functionality. Typically this is done by providing a demo account that has access to all features and functionality in your app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.